# What's the difference between JMP directly and JMP with a register eax

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a C function `A()` whose address is 0x2807fc.  I try this to call `A()`, and it jumps to `A()` as I expected

```
JMP  0x2807fc
```

But I try this, and it's wrong. Why? I'm just confused.

```
mov  eax,0x2807fc
JMP  eax
```

---

I find another interesting question

```
002807fc <task_b_main>:
void task_b_main(struct SHEET *sht_back)
{
    2807fc: 55                      push   %ebp
    2807fd: 89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
    2807ff: 83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
    struct BOOTINFO *bi = (struct BOOTINFO *)ADR_BOOTINFO;
    ..........
    }
```

I have a function, its address is 0x2807fc.

Then it's my ASM code and binary code about `JMP` (I want to jump to that function)

```
appjmp:     
JMP  0x2807fc   ; eip, cs
RET
================
00281310 <appjmp>:
281310: e9 e7 f4 ff ff          jmp    2807fc <task_b_main>
281315: c3
```

According to the reference

```
Jmp near =>  E9
```

`E9` indicates `JMP NEAR`，why the address follow the `E9` isn't `fc 07 28 00`  but `e7 f4 ff ff`, I don't know where it comes from? (But it does jump to the function as expected.)

Then I modify it as below

```
 appjmp:
 mov  eax,0x2807fc
 JMP  eax  
 ret
 ===================
 00281310 < appjmp >:
 281310:    b8 fc 07 28 00          mov    $0x2807fc,%eax
 281315:    ff e0                   jmp    *%eax
 281317:    c3                      ret
```

It looks like normal，but it's wrong, it can't jump to the function.

Could you tell me the reasons, and how to alter it so that it can jump to the function.

---

```
#define appjmpTest(addr) \
__asm__ ("ljmp $(3*8), %0" \
        : \
        :"i" (addr))

appjmpTest(&task_b_main-0x280000);
```

It's my solution.  I try FAR JMP with explicit `segment:offset`, and then it works.  (My C Code is at the third GDT selector, so there is $(3*8)).

Comment: One question per question is best, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try this to **call** A(),and it jumps to A() as I expected

It is possible to `jmp` to a function, but you won't be able to get back via `ret` if you didn't use the `call` instruction that pushes the return address on the stack!

> 'E9' indicates JMP NEAR，why the address follow the 'E9' isn't fc 07 28 00 but  e7 f4 ff ff ,I don't where it comes from？

That's because the 4 bytes that follow the 'E9' opcode are the *relative* displacement from the end of this `call` instruction to the actual destination (which in your case was 0x002807FC).
The value 0xFFFFF4E7 is calculated from:

```
0x002807FC - 0x00281315       ;Destination - NextInstruction
```

> It looks like normal，but it's wrong,it can't jump to the function.

It probably does, but since the function can't return successfully, you think it went wrong.

---

```
1. JMP  0x2807fc

2. mov  eax,0x2807fc
   JMP  eax
```

Both these methods of jumping are **near** jumps that jump to the same location. A **far** jump would only be possible with your first method and it would have taken the form:

```
jmp 0x0000:0x2807FC      ;segment,colon,offset
```

A jump is denoted **near**  when jumping stays within the same segment.
-->Intel prefers to call this **intrasegment**.

A jump is denoted **far** when jumping is between segments.
--> Intel prefers to call this **intersegment**.

The notions **near** and **far** have nothing to do with distance!

Comment: This answer is great, but it doesn't touch on the very first question that was asked: what is the difference between `jmp imm` and `mov reg, imm`+`jmp reg`. One is a near indirect jump, while the other is a far jump. Otherwise, they are both absolute jumps.

Comment: @Cody Gray  Thanks for your answer.I agree with you that  ` jmp reg` is _register indirect jump_,but why`jmp imm` is far jump?I remember that `jmp far imm` is _far jump_ rather than `jmp imm`.Well how should I alter `mov reg, imm+jmp reg` to make it be able to jump to '0x002807FC' like `jmp 0x002807FC `? Thanks very much!

Comment: @William You don't need to alter anything! Both are __near__ jumps that jump to the same location. __Near__ is when jumping within the same segment. __Far__ is when jumping between segments and this was not the case with your examples.

Comment: @Fifoernik  actually，the second one doesn't work,so may be they are different.Fortunately, I have solve it by another way.

Comment: @Fifoernik   I have post my answer,it's not the best,but it works!

Answer (score 0):

This

```
JMP  0x2807fc
```

and this

```
mov  eax,0x2807fc
JMP  eax
```

are not equvalent.

Best source are Intel [manuals](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) - in this case Vol 2A, section 3-488

First is of this category:

> JMP rel32
>
> Jump near, **relative**, RIP = RIP + 32-bit displacement sign extended to
>   64-bits

Second one:

> JMP r/m32
>
> Jump near, **absolute** indirect, address given in r/m32. Not supported in
>   64-bit mode.

relative vs absolute -> if EIP != 0 then first won't reach same address as the secondd one.

It is not obvious if you use absolute addresses in your code (really??) or labels and let assembler do the translation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but I still can't understand very clearly. '0x2807fc' is the address of  function named 'task_b_main' ,so `JMP task_b_main` is the same as `JMP  0x2807fc`.  '0x2807fc' isn't a relative address,actually according the machine code，compiler calculate the relative address and the value is 0xFFFFF4E7,current EIP is 0x00281315 ,and '0xFFFFF4E7'+'0x00281315'='0x2807fc'.So the target address of  `JMP  0x2807fc` is still '0x2807fc' ?